BitWig 5.2.4 .deb packaging - not installing
ADDITION
I went away to do some work, and when back and attempted the install again, I now see a 'already installed'
NEVER saw anything to suggest that!
It is installed!
I have recently been 'trying' to get back to Linux and testing various distro on a i3 1.7GHz - 12Gb Ram Toshiba Laptop and they 'all' install BitWig 5.2.4, but Ubuntu Studio (24.0.4 - Plasma 5.27.11)
BitWig 5.2.4 .deb packaging - not installing...
Why?
Regards
M
PS the Toshiba i3 is 'only' a tester laptop - once all works I will install on PC and a more powerful laptop (currently on WIN11-Pro 23H2)

I am getting older I guess!
I simply did go to the bitwig folder where the installation file is, then:
Sudo Apt install ./name of package
But I was not connected!
Surely more problems will come out... they usually do!

Might it be better to install via Flatpak as opposed to the .deb version?

in regard to installing Flatpak on Ubuntu you may find this Linuxiac article helpful
